# Unable to pass value in ajax

Tags: php

i am trying to pass value through the following code, but unable please anyone check maybe i am mistaking somewhere

```
<input type="button" name="vote" value="Yes" width="100" onclick="getVote('; echo "y".$info['autoid']; echo')"/>
```

the problem is in following line **"y".$info['autoid'];** if i remove **"y".** its works fine. but i want to pass y and product id.

basically i am trying to joint the y with the int.

**ok here is full code.**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function getVote(int)
  {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
    }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","../poll/"+int,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<div id="poll">
 <form>
poll - :
<input type="button" name="vote" value="Yes" width="100" onclick="getVote('; echo     "y".$info['autoid']; echo')"/>
<input type="button" name="vote" value="No" width="100" onclick="getVote('; echo   "n".$info['autoid']; echo')"/>
</form>
 </div>
```

**thanks guys...i found the other way we can pass "-" for yes and empty for "n"**

```
<input type="button" name="vote" value="Yes" width="100" onclick="getVote('; echo "-".$info['autoid']; echo')"/>
<input type="button" name="vote" value="No" width="100" onclick="getVote('; echo $info['autoid']; echo')"/>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do.  A little more context?

Comment: I assume that there's an `echo '` before this somewhere, to match with the `';` after `getVote(`? Please provide more of the code so we can see things like that.

Comment: php guys will understand its an ajax.....

Comment: do you want me to post full code...

Comment: `getVote()` is a JavaScript function that may well be asynchronous. But I guarantee you that neither familiarity with PHP nor with AJAX is making this comprehensible to me.

Comment: How is this in ANY possible way related to AJAX ? how can these mystical php guys you speak off deduce that code is related to AJAX ?

Comment: PHP guys will get offended and choose not to help you.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8zhmiS-1kw

Comment: @DanielFigueroa you know it !

Comment: ok guys...full code is posted....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int is a reserved word in javascript, also you should use something like JQuery to handle your ajax-calls.

Comment: ok can we pass two words like 0 and 12221...in above example.

Comment: my point is that your function header has a reserved word in it, I don't know if thats whats making your script fail, but change "int" to something else here [getVote(int)] and [xmlhttp.open("GET","../poll/"+int,true);]

Comment: u are right daniel....i found the other way...<input type="button" name="vote" value="Yes" width="100" onclick="getVote('; echo "-".$info['autoid']; echo')"/>
<input type="button" name="vote" value="No" width="100" onclick="getVote('; echo $info['autoid']; echo')"/>

Comment: i accept it as best answer...we can't pass string in int value...i have given the solution in my post...

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to contain double-quotes within double-quotes, and it's not clear where your php wrapper is?

I'd rewrite the onclick attribute as:

```
onclick="getvote( <?php echo "y{$info['autoid']}"?> "
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit mixed up around where the problem is.

Use this:

```
<input type="button" name="vote" value="Yes" width="100" onclick="getVote('y<?php echo $info['autoid']; ?>');"/>
```